# Create Session Authorize in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-core, authorize

I am working on a Web Application using Asp.net Core 1.1
My Login is a partial view that after Success Login set Session for UserId and UserName

Controller Code :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

And For HttpPost:

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public PartialViewResult Login(UserAccount user)
    {
        var accout = _context.userAccount.Where(u => u.UserName == user.UserName && u.Password == user.Password).FirstOrDefault();

        if (accout != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserID", accout.UserID.ToString());
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserName", accout.UserName);
            return PartialView("_welcome");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "UserName Or Password is InCorrect";
            return PartialView("_ErrorMessage");
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Now, My project has 2 areas. First "Admin" Area and second is "User" Area. Each area has some controllers and views.
I want the user to access only some of the views and controllers after Login.
How can i do it?

Comment: Using session to store login status is wrong. Session can be lost in many situations (application restart, changes in web.config). You should also read about `AuthorizeAttribute` and roles.

Comment: @LukLed thanks, can you suggest me any good tutorial?